# What's the easiest way to show rigorously that the integral form of Gauss's law follows from Coulomb's law?

Tags: real-analysis, vector-analysis, electromagnetism

Suppose that $\rho: \mathbb R^3 \to \mathbb R$ is a function that tells us the electric charge density at each point in space. According to Coulomb's law, the electric field at a point $x \in \mathbb R^3$ is
$$
\tag{1} E(x) = \frac{1}{4 \pi \epsilon_0} \int_{\mathbb R^3} \rho(y) \frac{x - y}{\|x - y \|^3} \, dy.
$$
**Question:** What is the easiest way to show rigorously that the function $E$ defined above satisfies the integral form of Gauss's law: if $\Omega \subset \mathbb R^3$ is a smooth $3$-manifold with boundary, then
$$
\tag{2} \int_{\partial \Omega} E \cdot dS = \frac{1}{\epsilon_0} \int_\Omega \rho(x) \, dx.
$$
Is it necessary to first show that
$$
\tag{3} \nabla \cdot E = \frac{\rho}{\epsilon_0},
$$
or is there a way to show that (1) implies (2) directly without going through (3)?

**Comments:**
Physics textbooks typically argue that (2) holds for the electric field due to a point charge, then argue that (2) follows for the field due to a general charge distribution by superposition. Once (2) is established, they derive (3) as a corollary using the divergence theorem. So the chain of logic is
$$
(1) \implies (2) \implies (3).
$$
This is a highly intuitive but non-rigorous argument. I wonder if there's a way to make it rigorous.

A rigorous proof that (3) follows from (1) can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4078996/40119). And it is easy to get from (3) to (2) using the divergence theorem. But I wonder if that is the most direct route from (1) to (2). Notably, that chain of reasoning
$$
(1) \implies (3) \implies (2). 
$$
differs from the highly intuitive physics textbook approach.

Since this question is about a rigorous proof of a mathematical fact, I believe it's a good fit for math.stackexchange.

Answer (score 1):

Use a Green's function. [This definition of $G$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_function#Green%27s_functions_for_the_Laplacian) satisfies $\nabla^2G(x,\,y)=\delta(x-y)$ (all derivatives herein are with respect to $x$), with $\delta$ the Dirac delta. Write $(1)$ as $E=\frac{1}{\epsilon_0}\int_{\Bbb R^3}\rho(y)\nabla G(x,\,y)dy$ so$$\nabla\cdot E(x)=\frac{1}{\epsilon_0}\int_{\Bbb R^3}\rho(y)\nabla^2G(x,\,y)dy=\frac{1}{\epsilon_0}\int_{\Bbb R^3}\rho(y)\delta(x-y)dy=\frac{\rho(x)}{\epsilon_0}.$$

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful. And then from this to the integral form of Gauss's law is easy using the divergence theorem.